# Implementing SpreadSheet client using google-api-java-client

Tags: google-api-java-client, google-sheets-api

I've been trying to implement a SpreadSheet client based on the calendar example.
I managed to get spreadsheets, worksheets feeds and entries, utilizing the parser and the @Key attribute.
([explanation here](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/1.2.1-alpha/com/google/api/client/googleapis/xml/atom/package-summary.html))
However when I got to the ListFeed response, the data is stored in  elements, so the @Key feature cannot be used
Is there any way to parse this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to parse , for example :

```
<author>
  <name>John Smith</name>
  <email>john.smith.example@gmail.com</email>
</author>
```

You need to create a class Author

```
public class Author {

 @Key("name")
 public String name;

 @Key("email")
 public String email

}
```

And in your feed class, you add :

```
  @Key("Author")
 Author author
```

That should do the trick.